# Scroll down half the screen size in Firefox

Tags: firefox, keyboard, scrolling

Is it possible to have the spacebar *not* scroll down the entire page in Firefox? Scrolling one line at a time (with the down arrow) is very slow, but scrolling the entire screen (with spacebar) sets me off and I loose focus.

Is there a way to make the spacebar scroll the page the equivalent of approximately half the screen?

Just to be clear. When pressing spacebar, instead of the line in the bottom of the screen bring brought to the top, the line in the bottom should be brought to the middle.

Comment: Hey, adjust your wheel mouse to scroll for example 10 lines, 20 lines... If you want to scroll one line, hold shift.

Comment: @kokbira I've adjusted the mouse wheel scroll, but I do most of my reading with my hands on my keyboard, so adjusting the keyboard scroll would be much more convenient.

Comment: If you find have a problem with reading after scrolling such a long leap, your problem isn't your browser scroll behaviour, it is your window size. Use a resizing tool to place the browser in a window half as high as your screen and just wide enough for the text + navigation. I prefer GridMove, but there are alternatives too.

Comment: This would also help with sites with a banner overlay that hides 2-3 lines of the page.

Answer (score 8):

Should be quite simple to accomplish in AutoHotkey.
Download autohotkey, and use the following script with it. The script detects if you are in a input box.

```
#NoEnv  
SendMode Input
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir% 
#IfWinActive, ahk_class MozillaWindowClass
{
    Space::
    If A_Cursor != IBeam
    {   
        Send {WheelDown 150}
    }else {
        Send {Space}
    }
    return
}
```

Then adjust the amount of scrollsteps you want to scroll at {WheelDown 150}
You can easily compile the script to an exefile if you want by using the Compiler that is included when you download autohotkey.

OR download this precompiled binary...
http://www.megaupload.com/?d=D58JPT4U

Comment: Would this affect typing into a textbox in Firefox?

Comment: Probably :( Missed that. But maybe you could extend the script. Scrollmode hotkey.

Comment: I have updated script now so it detects textboxes. ;-)

Comment: That kind of works... From my testing: it only detects that the cursor is on a textbox if the mouse cursor is also on top of the textbox, otherwise it just scrolls. I know it sounds weird, but I reproducing it right now on this comment box.

Comment: If it doesn't get fixed, I'll just bind it to ctrl-space or something.

Comment: Yep, it's designed that way. But I'm gonna see what I can do.

Comment: Well, wasn't the solution I was hoping to see here, but definitely an A for effort - doesn't look like there's going to be any easy way to do this in the browser itself.

Comment: Any idea how to do this in Linux?

Answer (score 1):

It's just an undeveloped idea, but maybe somebody will make it real:
A custom greasemonkey script, which detects space and shift-space keypresses, prevents default scroll behaviour, and programmatically scrolls half page.

Comment: Maybe a Jetpack addon?

Answer (score 0):

I use [vimium-C](https://github.com/gdh1995/vimium-c) add-on on Firefox which has the following keyboard shortcuts:

```
d       scroll down half a page
u       scroll up half a page
```

(There are several other similar add-ons which you might want to look into and choose the one that fits best to your needs, including the original [Vimium](https://github.com/philc/vimium))