# Disable Scroll Effects Windows 10 PageDown

Tags: windows-7, windows-10

So I have the same laptop running Windows 7 and Windows 10.  Is there a way to disable the scroll effect when pressing the Page Down key on Windows 10.  I like the page to just jump but I can't figure how to get it to do that on Windows 10 like Windows 7.  I will probably stay on Windows 7 until I can figure out a workaround.

Comment: What scroll effect? When pressing Page Down on which application in Win 10? page in which app (browser,  reader...)? Does the answer here help: https://superuser.com/questions/575417/how-can-i-make-the-page-up-and-page-down-keys-scroll-a-full-screenful-in-browser ?