# How to have space bar scroll half the page instead

Tags: macos, firefox, keyboard, pdf, scrolling

Can the space bar scroll behavior be modified in all apps (such as Firefox, pdf viewers, etc.)? It's dizzying to have space bar scroll the full page -- I often lose track of what I'm reading.

I found [this link](https://superuser.com/questions/307739/scroll-down-half-the-screen-size-in-firefox), but the answer is for Microsoft Windows and seems to be only for Firefox. Is there an operating system and app independent solution? Or if not, one for Firefox and OSX would be very helpful still.

Comment: A quick google search turned up empty. I'd even be interested in disabling the behavior, instead of just modifying the length of the jump, but no dice. Sucks.

Answer (score 2):

A modern answer (`keyconfig` doesn't use since the great FF extension purge) is to use [Saka Key](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/saka-key/). It's really meant to be a full-keyboard scrolling config (à la Vimperator) but I erased every shortcut (in the Extension page, click on the three dots and go to `Preferences`), and added this one:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found this [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20190417205438/http://widebrant.com/post/21099976115/adding-half-page-scrolling-to-firefox) that should solve your problem.

I've tried the solution myself, but I am using Ubuntu instead of OS X. Anyway I think this solution is general enough to solve your problem also, since it's firefox based.

Works with firefox, didn't look for a solution or alternative for chrome

---

Download the [keyconfig](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=48&t=72994%20keyconfig) extension (It seems a little bit outdated, but it is still working =D ).

Now look for "**Keyconfig...**" in the menus.

- Click **Add new key**
- In the *Name* textbox type something like "Half-page Scroll Down"
- Paste the following code, replacing the text `/*CODE*/`

> /* Down */
>
> window.content.scrollBy(0, window.content.innerHeight / 2);

- Click **OK**
- Now in the list look for "Half-page Scroll Down" and select it (the list may be alphabetically sorted)
- Click on the text field at the left size of the button Apply, and type the desired *hotkey*. In this case, you could press Space key of your keyboard
- Click **Apply** (Please don't forget this one :P )

Now to configure the scroll up just repeat the steps above using:

*Name* = "Half-page Scroll Up"

This code instead:

> /* Up */
>
> window.content.scrollBy(0, -(window.content.innerHeight / 2));

And *hotkey* = Press on your keyboard Shift+Space

(Don't forget apply :P)

---

***Bonus***:
Note that the codes used above could easily be changed to get other desired effects
like:

> /* Down */
>
> window.content.scrollBy(0, window.content.innerHeight / 3);

Scroll just 1/3 of the page instead of half! =)

And

> /* Down */
>
> window.content.scrollBy(0, 0);

Scroll does nothing at all (hey! Disables Space).